# C# Replace two specific commas in a string with many commas

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to change the date format in each line from commas to hyphens.  The index of the comma separating the month and day day and year varies.

```
   lines_in_List[i] = lines_in_List[i].Insert(0, cnt + ","); // Insert Draw # in 1st column

   string one_line = lines_in_List[i];
   // 0,5,1,2012,1,10,19,16,6,36,,,
   // 1,11,5,2012,49,35,23,37,38,28,,,
   // 2,12,10,2012,8,52,53,54,47,15,,,
   //  ^-^--^ replace the ',' with a '-'.

   StringBuilder changed = new StringBuilder(one_line);
   changed[3] = '-';
   changed[5] = '-';
   changed[3] = '-';
   lines_in_List[i] = changed.ToString();
}
```

Comment: *The index of the comma separating the month and day day and year varies*... varies based on **what**?

Comment: @EricJ. Whether the month/day is one digit or two

Comment: COnsider Split(',') and the building the date from the parsed fields.

Comment: TextFieldParser is great for parsing CSV files

Comment: @kenny: Split creates a lot of new String objects.  Not very efficient if you are parsing a really large file.

Comment: what about an inner loop to find the last comma of date (the 4th if I'm not wrong) ? and than replacing everything to the index of last comma with `one_line_substring.Replace(',','-')` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the overload of IndexOf that takes an initial offset to begin searching.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xkyx09y.aspx

```
int idxFirstComma = line.IndexOf(',');
int idxSecondComma = line.IndexOf(',', idxFirstComma+1);
int idxThirdComma = line.IndexOf(',', idxSecondComma+1);
```

Use those indices to do your replacements.

To efficiently replace those characters (without creating lots of temporary string instances), check this out:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/change-characters-string

That snippet converts the string to a character array, does the replacements, and creates one new string.

Comment: I was just writing that...you beat me to it

Comment: Nice! Didn't know about this overload.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this:

```
string modifiedLine = Regex.Replace(line, @"(^\d+,\d+),(\d+),(\d+)", @"$1-$2-$3")
```

And if you need to trim spaces at the beginning of the line, use this instead:

```
string modifiedLine = Regex.Replace(line, @"^[ \t]*(\d+,\d+),(\d+),(\d+)", @"$1-$2-$3")
```

And finally, if you want to retreive just the formatted date, use this:

```
string justTheDate = Regex.Replace(line, @"^[ \t]*\d+,(\d+),(\d+),(\d+).*", @"$1-$2-$3")
```

Comment: RegEx tends to be slower than direct string manipulation.  That can make quite a difference if the log file is large.

Comment: @EricJ. -- that is true. The person reading this question will need to appropriately pick a wise way to do it. If its something that is time and speed sensitive, then your answer is probably the best one. I am just offering an alternative way to accomplish it :)

Comment: Sure.  Regex surely has its place and may be appropriate for the OP.